# how to print a collection as valid code in scala

Tags: scala, reflection

Assume I have

```
val x = List("a","b","c")
```

I'd like to have a function `f` which when called, returns

```
List("a","b","c")
```

Currently, `println(x)` just prints `List(a,b,c)` which will not compile when compiled/pasted into an Scala-Notebook or Unit-Test.

I'm stuck to find a general solution which also works for `Seq[Double]` etc , I managed to get something for `Seq[String]` by re-adding the quotes, but I'm unable to get a proper solution for all collection types

Comment: by "returns" do you mean prints to console? As in you want to print a collection with the surrounding quotes?

Comment: Why do you need this?, this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I use it for example to copy small amounts of data from 1 notebook to another, or to write a small test based on the current state of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want custom type class `Show`

```
trait Show[T] {
  def show(t: T): String
}
trait LowPriorityShow {
  implicit def default[T]: Show[T] = _.toString
}
object Show extends LowPriorityShow {
  implicit val str: Show[String] = s => s""""$s""""
  // other exceptions for element types
  implicit def list[T: Show]: Show[List[T]] = _.map(show(_)).mkString("List(", ",", ")")
  implicit def seq[T: Show]:  Show[Seq[T]]  = _.map(show(_)).mkString("Seq(", ",", ")")
  // other exceptions for collection types
}

def show[T](t: T)(implicit s: Show[T]): String = s.show(t)

val x = List("a","b","c")
show(x) //List("a","b","c")
val x1 = Seq("a","b","c")
show(x1) //Seq("a","b","c")
```

You can try to replace instances for collections (`Show.list`, `Show.seq`...) with more generic

```
import shapeless.Typeable

implicit def collection[Col[X] <: Iterable[X], T: Show](implicit ev: Typeable[Col[_]]): Show[Col[T]] = {
  val col = Typeable[Col[_]].describe.takeWhile(_ != '[')
  _.map(show(_)).mkString(s"$col(", ",", ")")
}
```

You'll have to check yourself whether the result is always a valid code in Scala.